# Oculus Tiny Room, Directx, Loading a 3D Model into scene

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, directx-11, oculus

I am currently working on Oculus Rift PC SDK. Was trying to start off with something simpler like Tiny Room Demo(DX11). Saw this tutorial online to load a 3D model into the scene from external file (Rastertek 
Tutorial 7: 3D Model Rendering)

The way the Tiny Room Demo creates model is to hardcode the coordinates and renders it

```
TriangleSet walls;
    walls.AddSolidColorBox(10.1f, 0.0f, 20.0f, 10.0f, 4.0f, -20.0f, 0xff808080);  // Left Wall
    walls.AddSolidColorBox(10.0f, -0.1f, 20.1f, -10.0f, 4.0f, 20.0f, 0xff808080); // Back Wall
    walls.AddSolidColorBox(-10.0f, -0.1f, 20.0f, -10.1f, 4.0f, -20.0f, 0xff808080);   // Right Wall
    Add(
        new Model(&walls, XMFLOAT3(0, 0, 0), XMFLOAT4(0, 0, 0, 1),
            new Material(
                new Texture(false, 256, 256, Texture::AUTO_WALL)
            )
        )
    );

void AddSolidColorBox(float x1, float y1, float z1, float x2, float y2, float z2, uint32_t c)
{
    AddQuad(Vertex(XMFLOAT3(x1, y2, z1), ModifyColor(c, XMFLOAT3(x1, y2, z1)), z1, x1),
            Vertex(XMFLOAT3(x2, y2, z1), ModifyColor(c, XMFLOAT3(x2, y2, z1)), z1, x2),
            Vertex(XMFLOAT3(x1, y2, z2), ModifyColor(c, XMFLOAT3(x1, y2, z2)), z2, x1),
            Vertex(XMFLOAT3(x2, y2, z2), ModifyColor(c, XMFLOAT3(x2, y2, z2)), z2, x2));
...}

AddQuad(Vertex v0, Vertex v1, Vertex v2, Vertex v3) { AddTriangle(v0, v1, v2);  AddTriangle(v3, v2, v1); } 

void AddTriangle(Vertex v0, Vertex v1, Vertex v2)
{
    VALIDATE(numVertices <= (maxBuffer - 3), "Insufficient triangle set");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) Indices[numIndices++] = short(numVertices + i);
    Vertices[numVertices++] = v0;
    Vertices[numVertices++] = v1;
    Vertices[numVertices++] = v2;
}
```

Tried to load the model into the scene using a function from the tutorial

```
TriangleSet models;
    models.LoadModel("F:\\cube.txt");
    Add(
        new OBJModel(&models, XMFLOAT3(0, 0, 0), XMFLOAT4(0, 0, 0, 1),
            new OBJMaterial(
                new Texture(false, 256, 256, Texture::AUTO_WHITE)
                //new Texture(DirectX, L"wallpaper.jpg")
            )
        )
    );  //3D Model

void LoadModel(char* filename)
{
    ifstream fin;
    char input;


    // Open the model file.
    fin.open(filename);

    // Read up to the value of vertex count.
    fin.get(input);
    while (input != ':')
    {
        fin.get(input);
    }

    // Read in the vertex count.
    m_vertexCount = 0;
    fin >> m_vertexCount;

    // Read up to the beginning of the data.
    fin.get(input);
    while (input != ':')
    {
        fin.get(input);
    }
    fin.get(input);
    fin.get(input);

    // Read in the vertex data.
    for (int i = 0; i<m_vertexCount; i++)
    {
        Indices[numIndices++] = short(numVertices + i);
        //numVertices++; deleted
        fin >> Vertices[numVertices].Pos.x >> Vertices[numVertices].Pos.y >> Vertices[numVertices].Pos.z;
        fin >> Vertices[numVertices].U >> Vertices[numVertices].V;
        fin >> Normals[numVertices].Norm.x >> Normals[numVertices].Norm.y >> Normals[numVertices].Norm.z;
        Vertices[numVertices].C = ModifyColor(0xffffffff, Vertices[numVertices].Pos);
        numVertices+=1; //new statement
    }

    // Close the model file.
    fin.close();
}
```

I did not use the normal as from the tutorial it was meant for the texture of the object. Instead I defined the color to be solid yellow. Tried to keep the structure of loading the model as similar to Tiny Room Demo as possible.

I have used the same model, material and texture (vertex shader and pixel shader) as how Tiny Room Demo does. However what was rendered onto the scene did not appear as what it is supposed to be.

Did a step by step debugging to see if the coordinates were correctly loading into the Vertices[numVertices]. Seems like there is no issue. The file I tried to load was cube.txt

Vertex Count: 36

Data:

-1.0  1.0 -1.0 0.0 0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.0

1.0  1.0 -1.0 1.0 0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.0

-1.0 -1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0  0.0  0.0 -1.0

-1.0 -1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0  0.0  0.0 -1.0

1.0  1.0 -1.0 1.0 0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.0

1.0 -1.0 -1.0 1.0 1.0  0.0  0.0 -1.0

1.0  1.0 -1.0 0.0 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0

1.0  1.0  1.0 1.0 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0

1.0 -1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0

1.0 -1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0

1.0  1.0  1.0 1.0 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0

1.0 -1.0  1.0 1.0 1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0

1.0  1.0  1.0 0.0 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0

-1.0  1.0  1.0 1.0 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0

1.0 -1.0  1.0 0.0 1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0

1.0 -1.0  1.0 0.0 1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0

-1.0  1.0  1.0 1.0 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0

-1.0 -1.0  1.0 1.0 1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0

**...**

What was suppose to show up (except without the texture)
[3D cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV9HK.jpg)

What actually showed up was just fragments of triangle
[TinyRoomDemo + 3D cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4um8.jpg)

Unsure what went wrong. Please do advice! Thank you very much :)

Vertex and Index buffer

```
struct OBJModel
{
XMFLOAT3     Pos;
XMFLOAT4     Rot;
OBJMaterial   * Fill;
DataBuffer * VertexBuffer;
DataBuffer * IndexBuffer;
int          NumIndices;

OBJModel() : Fill(nullptr), VertexBuffer(nullptr), IndexBuffer(nullptr) {};
void Init(TriangleSet * t)
{
    NumIndices = t->numIndices;
    VertexBuffer = new DataBuffer(DIRECTX.Device, D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER, &t->Vertices[0], t->numVertices * sizeof(Vertex));
    IndexBuffer = new DataBuffer(DIRECTX.Device, D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER, &t->Indices[0], t->numIndices * sizeof(short));
}
```

**...**

```
DIRECTX.Context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
```

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

06/06/2017 edited:
3D Model data:

Vertex Count: 798

Data:

28.3005 0.415886 -45.8282 0.7216 0.720211 0 0 -1

28.3005 -0.809079 -45.8282 0.732222 0.720211 0 0 -1

-27.7441 -0.809079 -45.8282 0.732222 0.847836 0 0 -1

28.3005 0.415886 68.1056 0.459891 0.720286 0 1 -0

28.3005 0.415886 -45.8282 0.719341 0.720286 0 1 -0

-27.7441 0.415886 -45.8282 0.719341 0.847911 0 1 -0

28.3005 -0.809079 68.1056 0.721603 0.720211 0 0 1

28.3005 0.415886 68.1056 0.732225 0.720211 0 0 1

-27.7441 0.415886 68.1056 0.732225 0.847836 0 0 1

28.3005 -0.809079 -45.8282 0.459891 0.720298 0 -1 -0

28.3005 -0.809079 68.1056 0.719341 0.720298 0 -1 -0

-27.7441 -0.809079 68.1056 0.719341 0.847923 0 -1 -0

28.3005 0.415886 68.1056 0.719341 0.70683 1 0 -0

**...**

Comment: In your LoadModel function, it seems that you start the loop by incrementing numVertices. Therefore Vertices[0] doesn't have any value.

Comment: did u you use index buffer? or vertex buffer only? u might have screwed up indices if u used index buffer, also watch out if u used trianglestrip method of drawing triangles, based on vertices u provided u should use trianglelist

Comment: @Sly_TheKing I am using both vertex and index buffer. As well as a trianglelist. Have added the code into the post above. Thank you :)

Comment: @StefanAgartsson Didn't realise that. have amended the code. It appeared to be of a cube now but only showing 1 of the triangle that makes up the side. Have updated the code in the post above. Thank you :)
[updated tiny room demo with 3D cube](http://imgur.com/a/ztP4A)

Comment: SOLVED. OMG THANK YOU BOTH SO MUCH. I just realise I made a mistake in this statement too.

Indices[numIndices++] = short(numVertices + i);

should be Indices[numIndices++] = short(0+ i);

it screwed the Indices[ ].

Thank you so much for all the help! What a careless person I am :(

[finally loaded into the scene](http://imgur.com/a/n6F8e)

Comment: glad i could help :) i've done mistakes like yours zillion times, so from the picture i knew ur indices are wrong :D

Comment: @Sly_TheKing Hi, there seem to be a problem when I try to load more complex models like houses. Seems like it wasn't able to load into the scene properly. [3D HOUSE MODEL](http://imgur.com/a/M6gQ3). Ive checked NumIndices, numIndices and numVertices to ensure that the correct number has been loaded in but the 3D house doesn't appear in the scene fully...

Comment: @StefanAgartsson

Comment: I kind of understand the problem is similar that the indices might have issue. but I don't understand why did it work for the cube and not other model... So where could have gone wrong in this case.

Comment: hmmm... this looks like problem with triangle facing, i'll post my suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 0):

From the data u provided for the house, it seems like 1 triangle is facing in one way and second is facing the opposite way.

Use rasterizer **without** back culling to draw this object

Comment: I realized the issue. it seems not all obj file are triangularized. thus the vertices loaded are much lesser which explains the missing vertices for the triangles

Comment: then perhaps they are stored stored as triangle strip? try reading every 4 vertices and do the triangle strip.